# Sort comments by rating for the top two rows of the result and the rest by date?

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I have a table of comments, like so:

```
---------------------------
| comment | date | rating |
---------------------------
| a       | 1    |      1 |
---------------------------
| b       | 4    |      3 |
---------------------------
| c       | 7    |      2 |
---------------------------
| d       | 1    |     10 |
---------------------------
| e       | 3    |     20 |
---------------------------
```

I want to sort the table so that the two most rated comments always appear at the top of the result, independently of the date, and the rest of the comments are sorted by the date in descending order. The results should look like this:

```
---------------------------
| comment | date | rating |
---------------------------
| e       | 3    |     20 |
---------------------------
| d       | 1    |     10 |
---------------------------
| c       | 7    |      2 |
---------------------------
| b       | 4    |      3 |
---------------------------
| a       | 1    |      1 |
---------------------------
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do two SQL-Queries. The first one selects the two highest commands.

```
SELECT comment, date, rating FROM comments ORDER BY rating DESC Limit 2
```

And then you can just show the others and order them by date. Aren't you saving an ID for the comments table? If yes, you could also select the ID in the above query and then in the second query select all comments, ordered by date, that don't have the ID from the previous query.

Comment: Yes there's also unique id's for each comment. Problem is, I'm doing this on Android so it would be much nicer if I could get the result using one big query, is that possible or do I have to merge the results from your suggestion somehow?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible, however, this would be beyond my skills, since I'm fairly new so I guess someone else needs to help you on this one.

Comment: Come to think about it, I could do a simple join between the two results you refer to, this would definitely solve the issue, so I'm marking this as the correct answer.